# Vim: temporary normal mode while holding Alt in insert mode

Tags: vim, key-bindings, neovim

I wonder if there's a way to make the `Alt` (or another key) work like `Ctrl-o`, but for as long as the key is pressed. For example, if you're in insert mode and want to move 10 lines down and 2 words forward, you could hold `Alt`, press `10jww` and then release the `Alt` key. It is much faster than pressing `Ctrl-o` before each movement or leaving insert mode and having to enter it back again.

I did some remappings to use the main movement keys from insert mode while holding `Alt`:

```
inoremap <A-h> <C-o>h
inoremap <A-j> <C-o>j
inoremap <A-k> <C-o>k
inoremap <A-l> <C-o>l
inoremap <A-w> <C-o>w
inoremap <A-e> <C-o>e
inoremap <A-b> <C-o>b
```

But that is limited, if I wanted to use numbers to move multiple steps for example, I would need to map a new key binding for each movement and for each number.

If it was possible to do something like enter normal mode on `Alt` (keydown) and go back to insert on `Alt` (keyup), then all normal mode key bindings should be available only by holding one key.

Comment: I wander how this could make you faster if you have one hand anchored on a key...

Comment: Well, actually I use my left thumb to hold ```Alt``` while ```w```, ```e```, ```1```, ```2```, ```3```, ```4``` and ```5``` are easily reachable by my other fingers on the left hand and my right hand is free to press ```h```, ```j```, ```k```, ```l``` , ```b```, and the other numbers. Those would be the only important keys and I know that this mode wouldn't be worth to use with much longer key bindings.

Comment: You can make mappings that use a count?

Comment: Not those using ```Alt```, that's the main feature I'm looking for in them. I've just discovered how to make mappings that use count on this [article](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)#Supplying_a_count_to_a_map), but looks like ```Alt``` adds an extra ```3``` to the count, so if try to make it count 2 or 7 times, it ends up counting 23 or 73 times.